# What pros and cons in defining the locators in the constructor or outside in typescript?

Tags: typescript, protractor, ui-automation, pageobjects

I'm coming to protractor (typescript) test automation from java. As I see a lot of people in typescript world like to define the locators in the constructor, e.g.:

```
export default class SignInPage extends BasePage {
  private readonly _usernameInputLocator: By;
  private readonly _passwordInputLocator: By;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this._usernameInputLocator = by.name('username');
    this._passwordInputLocator = by.name('password');
  }

}
```

instead of my common view, e.g.:

```
export default class SignInPage extends BasePage {

  private readonly _usernameInputLocator: By = by.name('username');
  private readonly _passwordInputLocator: By = by.name('password');

}
```

Could you be so kind, to tell me what differences in those two approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no big difference. The first version lets you use constructor parameters or reference other attributes in your initialisers; the second is shorter and neater but internally the code just gets hoisted inside the constructor so makes no difference.

The generated javascript is the same in either case except that the second one with the automatically generated constructor tests for the existence of a super constructor before calling it.